# Json character encoding for IndexedDB

Tags: ajax, json, html, asp-classic, indexeddb

This is my ASP webservice that queries the db and provides a Json file/object:

```
<!--#include file="JSON_2.0.4.asp"-->
<!--#include file="JSON_UTIL_0.1.1.asp"-->
<%
Response.CodePage = 28591 
Response.CharSet = "ISO-8859-1"

'response.write("ç ã â é À á") -> characters are written correctly with or without the two lines above but not the json feed

Set Connection = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set Recordset = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")  
Connection.Open "Provider=sqloledb;SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=DB;UID=user;PWD=PASS;" 
QueryToJSON(Connection,"select field1, field2, field3, field4, FROM table").flush
%>
```

The response text:

> [{"col1":"value1","col2":"value1","col3":"value1"},
>           {"col1":"value2","col2":"value2","col3":"value2"},
>           {"col1":"value3","col2":"value3","col3":"value3"}]

The response json is not properly encoded replacing punctuation marks "\u00E9" and adding a lot of spaces in the middle and in the end of the values.
When I open this file directly in the browser it looks ok in exception of the replaced characters, but when I feed it as a xmlhttp.responseText to the IndexedDB it appears in the console.log  with a lot of spaces and line breaks throwing a "DataError: Data provided to an operation does not meet requirements." error.
I think the spaces and line breaks might be cause by the replaced characters, something like this "\n"

Update:

I've tried using **`"xhr.setRequestHeader( "Content-Type", "application/json", "Charset=ISO-8859-1");"`** in my ajax request but it's not working either

Comment: What is the part you don´t understand?
I need to properly encode my json file to my charset (ISO-8859-1) so I can feed it to the IndexedDB objecStore but as described above I'm getting a response with a lot of spaces and line breaks that throw a "DataError: Data provided to an operation does not meet requirements." error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figured it out!
The query to the DB was retrieving the fields with spaces at the end that were being somehow incremented as the program ran, just changed the query line to:

```
 QueryToJSON(Connection,"select rtrim(field1) field1, rtrim(field2) field2, rtrim(field3) field3, rtrim(field4) field4 FROM table").flush
```

Now the response is clean and already accepting the correct charset.